# How to index the constraints with PuLP in python

Tags: python, cplex, pulp

I would like to index the constraints in the CPLEX lp file like below:

```
_20160421_LHRSINBA0011_Cap#0:   X_20160421_LHRSIN00001_50454 <= 234.5
_20160421_LHRSINBA0015_Cap#1:   X_20160421_LHRSIN00002_50464 + X_20160421_LHRSYD00001_60314 <= 114.5
```

But I don't know how to do it with PuLP.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "index the constraints"?  Get the indices of the constraints with those names?

Answer (score 0):

If by indexing you mean change the name of each of the constraints so that you can retrieve them easily then it's simple:

```
problem += X_20160421_LHRSIN00001_50454 <= 234.5, "_20160421_LHRSINBA0011_Cap#0"
problem += X_20160421_LHRSIN00002_50464 + X_20160421_LHRSYD00001_60314 <= 114.5, "_20160421_LHRSINBA0015_Cap#1"
```

Then when you're searching for a particular constraint, you can use:

```
[constraint for (c_name, constraint) in problem.constraints.items() if "_Cap#1" in c_name]
```